# Staff of Resilence, do I lose the THP if I get disarmed or put away the staff?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items

I'm reading Adventurer's Vault 2 and the Staff of Resilience says:

> Power (Daily). Minor Action. You spend a Healing Surge but regain no hit points. Instead, you gain temporary hit points equal to twice your healing surge value.

My question is:
Do I lose the THP if I get disarmed or if I lose it or if I put it in my bag?

Answer (score 12):

**No, but...**

Once you have temporary hit points, it doesn't matter how you got them: if a cleric gave them to you and the cleric dies, you keep your THP. If you got them from an item and you lose the item, you keep your THP. If the DM granted you THP for doing something cool and the *DM* dies... well probably you should call an ambulance or something, but you've still got those THP.

*However*, from the Rules Compendium p259:

> **Temporary Hit Points**
>
> *Until a Rest:* A creature's temporary hit points last until they're reduced to 0 or until the creature takes a short or extended rest.

So you can use the Staff of Resilience before a fight, stow it, and switch to a more combat-oriented staff and still keep your THP, but the THP will disappear if you take a rest.

Answer (score 5):

No.

THP aren't a condition that can be removed if you lose what gave them to you, they are granted to you on top of your normal hit points.